# CI_Session has a deprecated constructor error after upgrading to codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Got this error after i upgraded the CI version from version 2 to version 3.

> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; CI_Session has a deprecated
>   constructor
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 55

Here is the line 55, **class  CI_Session {**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same isssue with an outdated library....The problem seems to be that you need to rebuild the constructor with the "__construct" method.

Comment: For reference you can check http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Hi, before i accept this as an answer you mean this one? from:   function CI_Sessions() , to:   function __construct()

Comment: Yes that should be the one,because you do not need to use a function with same name as the class as constructor anymore.

Comment: Just curious - If you have upgraded from CI 2 to CI 3 did you delete the system folder and replace it entirely with the new CI 3 system files. In CI 3 there is no libraries/Session.php - that is an old CI 2 file that shouldn't be there. The system was changed to system/libraries/Session/Session.php. Also what version CI 2.x had that old fashioned constructor?

Comment: I am currently using Codeigniter 3.1.5 and that is indeed the path to your session.I,actually didn't have this problem because I was using my own Database Session driver so there was no big problem for me to switch.I am now waiting for CI 4,because I know that it will not be backwards compatible and they rebuilt it entirely, so that will be a little bit weird at first,but I hope it will not be entirely different. For refference about version changes you can have a look at https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/changelog.html